# In-app update with TestFlight on iOS

Tags: ios, updates, in-app, testflight

My iPhone app has now entered into a beta phase. I am using [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/) to send the app to the testers. Everything works great, I publish the link, they download the app, no problem with any certificate or anything (true story, lol).

My only problem is I have absolutely no idea on how to send in-app updates. I saw on the latest SDK version that it's available, but I can't figure out how to do it ! Right now, if I upload a new build, and select "update & notify", an email is sent. How can I send a notification to the users, directly through my app, that a new version is available ? Right now I'm starting to think that this is not possible (if so, my bad). But I really thought I could do it !

As always, any help/link/doc is always appreciated ! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can force an upgrade.

Go into settings in the upper right corner and select the "gear" then choose "Area 51" (this is the new features area, still beta). From there you can select to turn on "Forced Upgrades":

> If you enable force upgrades on a build. The next time users open your build and there is an update available they will be forced to install the build before continuing.

Comment: Well, that's pretty good. If you answered that, I guess there is no way to let the user continue using the previous version, but just notify him of an update ? You know, have the best of both worlds :)

Comment: And a last question, if I upload build 1, then build 2, then I activate *Forced updates*, will it be applied to build 2 ? I mean if someone is using build 1, will he be notified to update to build 2, or should I activate it prior to uploading ? Thanks for your help, this beta section was still unknown to me :)

Comment: activate it before I would say but I haven't tested that.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I'll use this function !

Comment: I have enabled this on my app, but it doesn't notify the user in the app. Do I have to use checkpoints to make it trigger an in-app notice?

Comment: @jarjar Same question here; did you find an answer?

Comment: Did you guys integrate the SDK? I suppose it is only available when the testflight SDK is included in the build you try to upgrade...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have different Bundle versions when uploading your app. You can set your bundle version in your apps info.plist under Bundle version. change that value to something else and you will be prompted now you open the app to upgrade or skip.

Comment: You mean build, not bundle.  Also, you must *increase* the build #.  If you decrease it, it won't prompt the user to upgrade

Answer (score 0):

So far, my users where notified in the app without me having to do anything but call takeOff and (well here i'm not sure if this was necessary) use a few arbitrary checkpoints. They could choose wether or not they want to update their app now, later or never.

BUT apparently this has stopped working over the past few weeks, I'm receiving more and more feedback that the only way they got to know that there is an update available was through the email that is sent to them by testflight.