# Does Testflight no longer support in-app-notifications of new builds?

Tags: ios, ios7, testflight

So far, my users where notified in the app without me having to do anything but call takeOff and (well here i'm not sure if this was necessary) use a few arbitrary checkpoints. They could choose wether or not they want to update their app now, later or never.

BUT apparently this has stopped working over the past few weeks, I'm receiving more and more feedback that the only way they got to know that there is an update available was through the email that is sent to them by TestFlight.

Did they replace this with "force-upgrade"? [In-app update with TestFlight on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319138/in-app-update-with-testflight-on-ios) mentions that using force upgrade enables notifications, yet it forces them to update, which is not what i want.

Or has this something to do with the SDK 2.0 struggling with iOS7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an iOS 7 issue. We're working on work arounds. Here's a help article that explains it more: http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/1318463-in-app-updates-are-not-working-on-ios-7-what-should-i-do-