# Does Apple's TestFlight application auto update apps that external beta testers have installed?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, beta

I can see from my iTunes connect control panel how many users are on each version of the app I have in beta. When does TestFlight update those apps? Do they have to open TestFlight and manually choose to update? Does it happen automatically when they launch the app they are testing?

I can't seem to find any answer on Apple's documentation.

Comment: The only way to force end users to update is by forcing them when they launch the app with an outdated version. A lot of desktop programs do this but I don't remember coming across a mobile app that ever did.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They have to manually update it. A push notification and email is sent to let the user know that a new version is ready to be tested, but it's up to user to open test flight and install it.

Comment: Interesting... Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Is this the same for internal testers ? i can't find a way to make my internal testers update the app

Comment: @FaridAlHaddad: It's been long since last time I used test flight but I assume there was no change in relation to that and internat testers needs to follow the same procedure

Comment: @ClaudioRedi by uploading a new version OR build, it will send an email automatically for my users ?

Comment: @FaridAlHaddad: correct. An email is sent automatically

Comment: I don’t get it. I got an email about a new version, it says to click to open TestFlight, but no way to install the new version. What is going on

Comment: I found the new version by selecting the app in TestFlight, then Previous Builds > [new version] > Install. Totally makes Apple sense

Comment: As of yesterday, this is no longer true. TestFlight now supports automatic updates: https://www.macrumors.com/2020/11/11/testflight-app-automatic-update/

Answer (score 7):

As of November 11, 2020, TestFlight version 3.0 now supports automatic updates:

[image]

Source: https://www.macrumors.com/2020/11/11/testflight-app-automatic-update/

Answer (score 1):

After a while, I found a solution that works every time.

You need to remove the version from testing by selecting `Not Available for Testing`. Then save, approve and reselect the version you want to test and save again.

This will make all your TestFlight users receive a notification with the update (event if they have a different version installed).

Comment: That option is not available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It *might* be possible to do a force upgrade, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12319198/330067, however I didn't find any details so far.

Comment: In that link they talk about Area51 - which is no longer available since Apple took over and included it into iTunesConnect. So right now Claudio is right, there is no option.