# Auto update iPad app without app store

Tags: ios, swift

I have an iPad app and I don't want to publish on app store.

I want to reconfigure the app from server i.e. if the flow of the app was:

Page 1 -> Page 2 -> Page 3

And I change data in the database to:

Page 1 -> Page 3 -> Page 2

My app should be reconfigured. I would also like new pages to be added in my app.

How to download the Swift files in user's app, compile it on the fly and update the app without user's intervention or through app store?

This is a private app and won't be published on app store.

Comment: In that case, do a web app...

Comment: @Dean - I want it to run iPad app. In native app and not browser URL.

Comment: The problem is that it is NOT possible to compile on the iPad side.

Comment: Either you make an app that contains a web view only ; with a web app inside

Comment: Or you make extra complicated swift code with a config load that you pull from your server, but you will need some updates at some times

Comment: Have a look at TestFlight, which enables OTA updating of an app without publishing it to the AppStore. You could also look at developing the app as an Enterprise app, but I don't have experience with that approach, so can't say if it would help you for sure.

Comment: @DávidPásztor - TestFlight will only help in inviting users, not in updating the app.

Comment: You can update the app in TestFlight as well, but it won't be automatic, the users will need to update it by opening the TestFlight app after they receive a notification about the update. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30906075/does-apples-testflight-application-auto-update-apps-that-external-beta-testers)

Answer (score 2):

> How to download the Swift files in user's app, compile it on the fly and update the app without user's intervention or through app store?

You can't.

You can, however, design your app to have UI not hardcoded in the app, but defined in some configuration file (i.e. in JSON format) which you would download at app launch. You would need to implement functions to create UI elements from their JSON definitions, etc.

Comment: are there any example apps which can create UI element using JSON?

Answer (score 0):

No, This is not how it works on iOS. You can't achieve this requirement through Native iOS development. You have to create a web app. You can build the app using **React-Native** or **PhoneGap** cross platform environments. Again there, without publishing app store you can't share iOS .ipa file like the .apk file in android. In that case, you have to buy **Enterprise developer account** and share.

Another option like building a UI using JSON is very tricky and takes lots of efforts. In case if you really want to do like this go for it.

Comment: are there any examples of building UI using JSON?